# sites are in the middle of the broswer Safari

Tags: safari

I went to Apple retail store and had a look at Macbook Pro and Macbook Air. What I have noticed about them when I start browsing the web is that all sites are in the middle of of broswer screen so they don't get fit to the whole screen. Alaways there is a space in the right and in the left!

I know that you can Zoom in but I'm looking for a standard thing not zooming. When I asked someone about this he told me that this is the standard in Appple, is that true? or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a link to some screenshot of a problematic site.

Comment: welcome to the world of large screens/resolutions, most websites are designed to fit the most common screen resolutions, something like 1024x768 or 1360x 768 , when you have a much higher screen resolution you end  up with a lots of empty space on both sides of the content

Comment: This is normal. Most Macs have high-resolution displays, well beyond Full HD, which leads to small text. Hence we have the need for stuff like DPI scaling. macOS (OS X) tends to be better than Windows on high-DPI displays, but recent Windows versions, especially since Windows 8.1, have much-improved DPI scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean because recall that the higher your screen resolution the more likely sites left/right borders will be blank (resulting in horizontal centering).  For example on my computer (Win7, rez: 2000x2x000) this site and most other sites i see content centered horizontally.  Here on SuperUser i see two giant empty white borders on the left and right with this content area smack-dab in the center.  This is perfectly normal.

I could use the zoom feature or change my Firefox setting to auto-zoom to fit content to the screen but i dont mind it at all.  If anything i prefer this way; i see more of the page content than i would if it auto-fit -- removing the empty borders.

If you dont like what Safari is doing you may be able to go into its about:config area (if it has one?) or dload a plugin to auto-fit.  I know a plugin like that exists for FF but i have no use for it.